# How do I troubleshoot SerialPort.Read() always return 0 in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have communicating to Display monitor using RS-232C 9-Pin D-Sub to Stereo Cable to control power ON/OFF, Volume Up/Down etc. I created a sample program based on Microsoft Docs System.IO.Ports. I can open COM PORT, write some byte arrays (based on protocol document) and no issue. But, reading in another thread always time out and receives '0' only. According to document, I should receive ACK or NAK (which will send back to me as byte array starting with 0xAA as well). I call Write() method in driver main class.

How can I troubleshoot for this issue? My reading byte array method is wrong? Thank you all for the input.

```
public class ComPortDemo
{
    private static bool _continue;
    private static SerialPort _serialPort;

    public ComPortDemo()
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort
        {
            PortName = "COM1",
            Parity = Parity.None,
            StopBits = StopBits.One,
            BaudRate = 9600,
            DataBits = 8,
            WriteTimeout = 2000,
            ReadTimeout = 5000,
            Handshake = Handshake.None,
        };

        _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortOnDataReceived;
        _serialPort.ErrorReceived += SerialPortOnErrorReceived;
        _serialPort.PinChanged += SerialPortOnPinChanged;
        _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
        _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
    }

    private void SerialPortOnPinChanged(object sender, SerialPinChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Pin changed event occurred. " + e.EventType);
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        int bufferLength = 6;
        byte[] commands = new byte[bufferLength];

        commands[0] = 0xAA;
        commands[1] = 0x11;
        commands[2] = 0x02;
        commands[3] = 0x01;
        commands[4] = 0x01;
        commands[5] = 0x15;

        if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
            _serialPort.Close();

        _serialPort.Open();
        _continue = true;
        Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);
        readThread.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Reader thread started and wait for response..");

        Console.Write("Sent: ");
        foreach (var command in commands)
        {
            Console.Write($"0x{command:X2} ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        _serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
        _serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
        _serialPort.Write(commands, 0, commands.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("ENTER to end reading thread..");
        Console.ReadLine();
        _continue = false;
        readThread.Join();
    }

    private static void SerialPortOnErrorReceived(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("serial port on error : " + e.EventType);
    }

    private static void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //var serialPort = (SerialPort) sender;
        //string data = serialPort.ReadExisting();
        //Console.WriteLine($"{data}");
        Console.WriteLine("data received event");
    }

    public static void Read()
    {

        while (_continue)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_serialPort.BytesToRead <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No data to read");
                }

                byte[] buffer = new byte[7];
                Console.WriteLine("trying to read..");
                int readByte = _serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Console.WriteLine($"Read byte : {readByte}");
                //if (readByte > 0)
                foreach (var b in buffer)
                    Console.Write($"0x{b:X2} ");

            }
            catch (TimeoutException toe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(toe.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _continue = false;
        if(_serialPort.IsOpen)
            _serialPort.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some digital protocol analyzing tool? If not, I suggest you to check if you need some pull-up/pull-down resistors on your Rx according to your schematics

Comment: @vasily.sib I use Serial Port Monitor software to check port traffic. I can verify that write data status is always successful and read is always timeout, too.

Comment: I mean hardware digital protocol analyzing tool, so you can check if your monitor Tx is actually sending something

Comment: *"I can open COM PORT, write some byte arrays ... and no issue."* -- That's an incomplete description.  Does the monitor respond (i.e. perform the command) in any way, e.g. a power OFF?    *"But, reading in another thread ..."* -- For a basic request-response dialogue as this situation has, separate threads for writing and reading is overly complex and not necessary.  (Also the OS buffers the data, and your program doesn't need to be concerned about data timing.)  Try simplifying the program to a loop (or sequences) that writes the request and then reads the response.

Comment: `_serialPort.Read` has known issues, it's recommented you use `ReadByte` or `ReadLine`.  However, `ReadLine` is looking for a terminator to know it received the whole line, so you would need to set the correct character.  I personally like to use the `DataReceived` event and use `ReadExisting()`, I've been using that for years with no issues.

Comment: @vasily.sib I am testing my program using remote, so it would not be easy to setup.

Comment: @Baddack The monitor does not response at all. I was testing using sample program from Microsoft. I have not used `ReadByte` before, I will try that with `DataReceived` event. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If You can, use my simple wrapper of COM port - it uses base streams and TPL library, therefore should eliminate some, maybe even most problems with threading work needed.

You will have to create a custom ICommunicationDeviceSettings implementation that will hold typical serial port settings (take a look at SetupDeviceOptions method, You will know what exactly is needed).

i hope that it will help You. Bare in mind that this implementation was made for long message transfer, but still - should work for You.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SerialPortWrapper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps SerialPort for future use with interfaces
    /// </summary>
    public class SerialPortAdapter : ICommunicationDeviceAsync
    {
        private readonly SerialPort _port = new SerialPort();
        private Encoding _encoding;
        private const int ByteBufferSize = 4092;    // Optimal size of max single data portion received buffer
        private byte[] _buffer = new byte[ByteBufferSize];

        private readonly object _lock = new object();
        private bool _disposed;

        public event EventHandler<string> DataReceived;

        public SerialPortAdapter(ICommunicationDeviceSettings settings) => Setup(settings);

        public bool IsOpen => _port?.IsOpen == true;
        public int ConfirmationTimeout { get; private set; }
        public int CompletitionTimeout { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets up all of the necessary parameters for this instance of the device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="settings">Configuration from AppSettings for this type of device</param>
        /// <returns>True if successful</returns>
        public void Setup(ICommunicationDeviceSettings settings)
        {
            if (!(settings is SerialPortSettings set))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settings));

            SetUpDeviceOptions(set);
        }

        private bool PortNumberExists(int portNumber) =>
            SerialPort.GetPortNames().Contains($"COM{portNumber}");

        private void SetUpDeviceOptions(SerialPortSettings settings)
        {
            _port.PortName = $"COM{settings.PortNumber}";
            _port.BaudRate = settings.BaudRate;
            _port.DataBits = settings.DataBits;
            _port.Parity = settings.Parity;
            _port.StopBits = settings.StopBits;
            _port.ReadTimeout = settings.ReadTimeout;
            _port.WriteTimeout = settings.WriteTimeout;
            _encoding = _port.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(settings.Encoding);
            _port.DtrEnable = false;
            _port.RtsEnable = false;
            _port.DiscardNull = true;
            CompletitionTimeout = settings.CompletitionTimeout;
            ConfirmationTimeout = settings.ConfirmationTimeout;
            Name = settings.Name;
        }

        public void Open()
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (!_port.IsOpen)
                    _port.Open();
            }
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            DiscardInBuffer();
            _port.Close();
        }

        public async Task CloseAsync()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                DiscardInBuffer();
                _port.Close();
            })
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public string Receive()
        {
            if (!_port.IsOpen)
                return string.Empty;

            try
            {
                int bytesRead = _port.Read(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length);
                string rawData = _encoding.GetString(_buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                OnDataReceived(rawData);
                return rawData;
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                return string.Empty; // Receiving failed - port closed or disconnected
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constantly monitors incoming communication data, filters it and generates Commands (ICommandModel)
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<string> ReceiveAsync(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            if (!_port.IsOpen)
                return string.Empty;

            try
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                int bytesRead = await _port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
                string rawData = _encoding.GetString(_buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                OnDataReceived(rawData);
                return rawData;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (ex is IOException || ex is OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // Only known way to handle sudden port failure AND cancellation - known SerialPort implementation hiccup.
                throw new OperationCanceledException("System IO exception in BaseStream.ReadAsync - handled, expected, re-thrown. Either task was canceled or port has been closed", ex, ct);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a raw data string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">Single data string to transfer</param>
        /// <returns>True if sending was successful</returns>
        public bool Send(string data)
        {
            if (!CanSend(data))
                return false;

            byte[] buffer = _encoding.GetBytes(data);
            try
            {
                _port.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a raw data string asynchronously.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">Single data string to transfer</param>
        /// <returns>True if sending was successful</returns>
        public async Task<bool> SendAsync(string data, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            if (!CanSend(data))
                return false;

            byte[] buffer = _encoding.GetBytes(data);
            try
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                await _port.BaseStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool CanSend(string data) => !IsOpen || string.IsNullOrEmpty(data);

        /// <summary>
        /// Clears data in 'received' buffer
        /// </summary>
        public void DiscardInBuffer()
        {
            _port.BaseStream.Flush();
            _port.DiscardInBuffer();
            _buffer = new byte[ByteBufferSize];
        }

        protected virtual void OnDataReceived(string rawData) => DataReceived?.Invoke(this, rawData);

        #region IDisposable implementation

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_disposed)
                return;

            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_port?.IsOpen ?? false)
                    _port.Close();
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }

        #endregion IDisposable implementation
    }
}
```